# Find Score for each keyword from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Hi i have a string and wanted to find importance of each word from string on the basis of its frequency in below dataframe (DF) of two columns :`['description','tags']`

```
string = `welcome to youtube channel name tesla free energy `

DF : (Size of DF is almost 1 million)

      ------      -------------
       Tag         Description
      ------      -------------
        111         ['my life is all about youtube it gives me happiness i have learn a lot about enery and its transmission']    
        222         ['tesla promised to give free energy to everyone free energy free']
        333         ['its all about science and technology and scientific experiments of given technology']
        444         ['my life is all about youtube energy free']


  O/P  Dataframe: 

      --------      -------------        ---------- 
       Words         Importance           Weights
      ---------     -------------        ----------
       welcome          {}                   {}              # As no word 'welcome' present in dataframe, empty dict
         to            {222:2}               {222:100}
       youtube       {111:1, 444:1}          {111:50, 444:50}
       channel          {}                   {}             # As no word 'channel' present in dataframe, empty dict
        name            {}                   {}            # As no word 'name' present in dataframe, empty dict
        tesla          {222:1}               {222:100}
        free         {222:3, 444:1}          {222:75, 444:25}
        energy       {222:2, 111:1, 444:1}   {222:50, 111:25, 444:25}
```

In Output Dataframe there are three columns :

```
1) Words : each word appear in sentence
2) Importance : Count of each word appear in each tag example : "free" appears 3 times in tag 222 and 1 time in tag 441
3) weights : weight of each word appears in each document / total no of time word appear in Dataframe. example : "free" appears 4 times in dataframe in which 3 times in tag 222 so (3/4)*100 = 75 and 1 time appears in tag 441 so (1/4)*100 = 25
```

Any Help is appreciated. Thank You!
(please ignore meaning of sentences as they are random)